# Not be able to change image of UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uibutton

I want to set the image of button on viewWillAppear.

I have tried following all codes -

```
UIButton *front;
    UIImage *temp= [UIImage imageNamed:@"06_asystole.jpg"];
        [front setBackgroundImage:temp forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        //front.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"06_asystole.jpg"];
       /// [front setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"06_asystole.jpg" forState:UIControlStateNormal]];
       // [front setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"06_asystole.jpg" forState:UIControlStateNormal]];
```

I have also set the IBOutlet to button and assign it in XIB.

I dont know why button's image cant be set.

Thanks..

Comment: is front the name of the image or the button?

Comment: What happens if you do `NSLog(@"%@", temp);` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This **won't** work:

```
UIButton *front = [[UIButton alloc]init];
UIImage *temp= [UIImage imageNamed:@"06_asystole.jpg"];
[front setBackgroundImage:temp forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

You want to change the `backgroundImage` of an existing `UIButton`. Either you add `front` to your view now and remove the old one, or use the existing buttons name instead of `front`.

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@",button);` and post the output. // Is "06_asystole.jpg" a part your bundle?

Comment: NSLog is - <UIButton: 0x6860ba0; frame = (0 90; 480 144); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x6860cf0>>

Comment: So, don't try to create a new button! You need to update your existing button using `[nameOfYourIBOutletButton setBackgroundImage:temp forState:UIControlStateNormal];` is this image a part of your bundle? Maybe you need to make a clean and add your image file to your target (Click your Project -> Click your Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle resources -> Add image)... I bet the image is just not inside your app.

Comment: YES image is part of bundle. I have tried your code and cleaned but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

```
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"06_asystole.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
btn.frame = CGRectMake(40, 140, 240, 30); //this should be something valid for you...
UIImage *temp= [UIImage imageNamed:@"06_asystole.jpg"];
        [btn setBackgroundImage:temp forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

the frame should be the size of the image or something useful to you.

If you correctly linked the button in the xib you should be able to edit the button from it directly from the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
UIButton *front = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"06_asystole.jpg"];
[front setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Hope this will work.

If you already added a button to your xib, then no need to create a new one.
You can set images to that button via code or via xib like follows,

[image: Button image via xib]
Select your button in the xib and set the image property on the attribute inspector.

Check this link for UIButton class reference.[link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue by re-adding image in my app. Though i have already added image to bundle, it didnt get reference of that image. so i have deleted old image and re-added it. Than it works fine.

Thanks all for helping. : )

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```